# Error on jquery tokeninput plugin has "TypeError: term is undefined"

Tags: php, javascript, jquery

```
<input type="text" id="demo-input-prevent-duplicates" name="targ_country" />
 <script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        var host = window.location.protocol+"//"+window.location.hostname;
        jQuery("#demo-input-prevent-duplicates").tokenInput(host+"/forms/campaign_location.php?action=country", {
        preventDuplicates: true,
        theme: "facebook",
        crossDomain: true
    });
    });
</script>
```

**/forms/campaign_location.php file**

```
<?php
if( isset( $_GET['action'] ) && isset( $_GET['q'] ) ) {

    $search = $db->clean( $_GET['q'] );
    $query = sprintf("SELECT CountryId, Country from countries WHERE Country LIKE '%%%s%%' ORDER BY Country DESC LIMIT 10", mysql_real_escape_string($_GET["q"]));
    $result = array();
    $rs = mysql_query($query) or die( mysql_error() );

    while( $row = mysql_fetch_object( $rs ) ) {
        $result[] = $row;
    }

    # JSON-encode the response
    $json_response = json_encode($result);

    if($_GET["callback"]) {
        $json_response = $_GET["callback"] . "(" . $json_response . ")";
    }       
    echo $json_response;
}
?>
```

This is the error i'm getting:
[image]
This is the code on line 783:
[image]
What seemed to be the problem here? I was just following all the instructions in the src folder of tokeninput. I even downloaded their latest version which is in this website: https://github.com/loopj/jquery-tokeninput.

Your help would be greatly appreciated and rewarded!

Thanks!

Comment: what is the output of `$json_response`?

Comment: sample output: jQuery17108566799442267607_1347521889033([{"CountryId":"268","Country":"Western Samoa"},{"CountryId":"267","Country":"Western Sahara"},{"CountryId":"255","Country":"United States Minor Outlying Islands"},{"CountryId":"254","Country":"United States"},{"CountryId":"253","Country":"United Kingdom"},{"CountryId":"252","Country":"United Arab Emirates"},{"CountryId":"216","Country":"Serbia and Montenegro"},{"CountryId":"275","Country":"Palestinian Territory, Occupied"},{"CountryId":"166","Country":"Montenegro"},{"CountryId":"160","Country":"Micronesia, Federated States of"}])

Comment: According to the docs in the plugin, the format should be `{"id":"253","name":"United Kingdom"},`  Have you tried that?

Comment: Yes i have tried that one but still aint working. THe reason why that's the format it's because I added a crossDomain: true

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add the following option to the tokenInput call:

```
propertyToSearch: "Country"
```

Comment: Wow! This works like a charm! Thanks for this one! I haven't read it in the docs. :)

Comment: I got another problem, The plugin thinks that the country that I searched is a duplicate one. Here is the video http://elsonsolano.com/screenshot/2012-09-13_1724.swf I'm having a hard time explaining it here.

Comment: Did you take a look on the video? If yes, then you will get it from there. The link is above our comment

Comment: Duplicate checking uses the `id` property, but you're not returning it in your JSON. Change the SQL to `SELECT CountryID AS id, ...`.

Comment: Wow! So this plugin identifies 2 properties , id and name properties. Thanks for your help! :)